$L^2(\mathbb{R})$ 1-form not differential of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
In my attempt to solve following exercise:


Construct a smooth 1-form on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\int |\psi|^2 dt < \infty$ for which there exists no function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int |f|^2 dt < \infty$ and $df = \psi$.
Can this be arranged such that the corresponding $L^2$-cohomology class projects to the trivial class in the reduced cohomology group $\overline{H}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}))$


As was pointed out in the comments, a Gaussian ($\psi(t) dt =e^{-t^2} dt$) satisfies the property in 1.
However, I don't know how to approach the second part.
By my understanding, we have for $M$ an $n$ dimensional manifold: $$\Omega^{0,2}(M) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \Omega^{1,2}(M) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \Omega^{2,2}(M) \rightarrow \cdots$$
If I write $d_0$ for the first $d$ and $d_1$ for the second; I understand $H^{1,2}(M)$ as $\mathrm{ker}(d_1)/\mathrm{im}(d_0)$ ($ =: H^{1,2}(M)$) and $\overline{H}^{1,2}(M)$ is obtained when taking the closure of $\mathrm{im}(d_0)$. Where the kernel is defined as:
$$\mathrm{ker}(d_1) := \{ \rho \in L^{1,2}(M) : \int \rho \land d\varphi = 0 \text{, $\varphi$ an $(n-2)$ smooth compactly supp. form} \} $$
(Definition which I know I am not fully comfortable with yet)
However in this case $n=1$ and so there cannot be $d_1: \Omega^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \Omega^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$. Also, the $\psi$ would be an $(-1)$-form. I'd guess (intuitively relating it to exactness) that we can consider $d_1 : \Omega^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow 0$ ? If i stick stubbornly to the $\mathrm{ker}$ definition, "$d\varphi$" in the definition would be a $0$-form (let's call it $\alpha$) and I find myself unsure about how to proceed: Is $\alpha$ trivial or is $\rho \land \alpha = \rho \alpha$?
I am only reasonably sure that:

$ H^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) \ni (\psi \  dt ) \neq df$ and thus we exclude the possibility that $\psi \ dt \in \mathrm{im}(d_0)$.


In general, $\int |\psi|^2,dt$ makes no sense. I presume that you (or the author) is writing $\psi=g(t),dt$ using the global coordinate $t$ on $\Bbb R$, and this is the integral $\int g^2,dt$? So now we're talking about $g=f'$ and you want $g\in L^2$ but no $f\in L^2$ with $g=f'$. The Arnold link is about something entirely different — the presence of topology in deciding whether a closed $1$-form (say, on $S^1$ or $\Bbb R^2-{0}$) is exact.

Yes. That is correct.

Can't you easily write down a continuous function $g\in L^2$ so that any $f$ satisfying $g=f'$ is not in $L^2$? You can then smooth it (perhaps not with an explicit formula).

Are you trying to find an $L^2$ function $f$ such that its antiderivative is not in $L^2$? I'm not a geometer so this is written a bit differently than I think of things. If so, there is a very simple example in the Gaussian.

There is a very general class of functions satisfying this property. Let $g$ be any function which is in $L^1(\Bbb{R})\cap L^2(\Bbb{R})$ and to avoid trivialities let’s say it is $C^k$ $(k\geq 0)$ and strictly positive on all of $\Bbb{R}$. If $f$ is an antiderivative of $g$ then there is an $a\in\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=\int_a^xg(t)\,dt$. This is a $C^{k+1}$ antiderivative of $g$ and the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\int_a^{\infty}g(t)\,dt$ exists (since $g$ is in $L^1$) and is strictly positive (also: the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ exists as well, and it is negative). Hence, $f$ does not lie in any of the $L^p$ spaces with $p\in [1,\infty)$; it only lies in $L^{\infty}$.
Now the question arises as to whether such functions actually exist.
My natural thought process for constructing them is the following:

If you start off with the piecewise smooth case, then just make $g$ constantly equal to $1$ for $t\in [-R,R]$ and then outside this interval, make it equal to $\frac{c}{|t|^{\alpha}}$ for a suitable constant $c$ and for any $\alpha>1$. Then, $g$ will be positive, and it obviously lies in $L^1\cap L^2$ due to the fast enough decay at infinity (actually this $g$ lies in each $L^p$ for $p\in [1,\infty]$, by obvious inspection). Now, to get a $C^{\infty}$ example, you just need to use some bump functions/partitions of unity to smooth things out/patch things together.

But this actually brings up an even easier collection of examples:

Consider any function $g$ which is $C^{\infty}$, strictly positive, an which is in $L^1(\Bbb{R})\cap L^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$. Then a simple application of Holder’s inequality shows that for each $p\in [1,\infty]$, $g$ lies in $L^p(\Bbb{R})$. A concrete example is the Gaussian function $g(t)=e^{-t^2}$, as mentioned in the comments.


I didn't notice your answer, as the post was in edit mode for hours (whilst I was trying to get an understanding of the topic). For 1. I realized that it was the formulation in terms of 1-forms that threw me off.
